# Images not shrinking proportionally with %?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, image-scaling

Okay, so I'm am simply trying to reduce the size of the social icons in `.jpg` using `width:10%;`. Instead of shrinking proportionally it's **squishy**. **Images sizes i am using is 250px by 250px for social icons**  The images need to grow relative to screen sizes. Any ideas?

HTML

```
            <div class="social-footer">
            <h3 class="connect-us-title">Connect With Us</h3>
            <div class="social-flex">
                <img class="social-icon" src="img/desktop/images/twitter.jpg">                   
                <img class="social-icon" src="img/desktop/images/insta.jpg">                     
                <img class="social-icon" src="img/desktop/images/fb.jpg">                       
            </div>               
        </div>
```

CSS

```
    /* SOCIAL */
.social-footer {
    margin: 2rem 0;
}
.social-icon {      
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
 }

.social-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `align-items` is `stretch`, which will cause flex children to `stretch` to fill the height of the parent. To disable that, just use another value for `align-items`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

```css
/* SOCIAL */
.social-footer {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}
.social-icon {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
}

.social-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-footer">
  <h3 class="connect-us-title">Connect With Us</h3>
  <div class="social-flex">
    <img class="social-icon" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
    <img class="social-icon" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
    <img class="social-icon" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing max-width: 100%;

Or turn max-width: 10%

Answer (score 0):

Set your `height` to 10% since you want it to be proportional to the `width`